# code first foreign key relationship with on delete set null

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have three classes `UserProfile`, `Groups` and `Contacts`. I want to
delete a `Group` without deleting its `Contacts`. `GroupID` in `Contacts` table
should be set to `null` when the `Group` is deleted. What to do?

The three classes:

```cs
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Groups
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Group")]
    public int? GroupID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public Prefix? Prefix { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: set database relations options like so cascade on delete on another option

Comment: please describe,How it would?

Comment: in management studio you must open relations of your tables and set there option (like so - on cascade deletes)